# Doctrine2 with postgres error

Tags: postgresql, exception, doctrine, boolean

i tried to make a simple query with doctrine and i get an error. I dont understand.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$dql = "SELECT n FROM Bundle:entity n WHERE n.value = true";
$negociaciones = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```

The system throw an exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: no existe la columna s0_.othervalue LINE 1
```

obviusly value and other value exists in the table and if i exec the query generated manualy works fine.

I dont understand but i need help!

Comment: Fixed. The problem was in a bad Database selectión.